# Pull comment count from a LinkedIn post in python using Selenium & Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a python script that pulls performance data from my own personal LinkedIn profile via web scraping using Selenium & BeautifulSoup.

I'm able to successfully reach my profile via Chrome and extract some data but comments seem to be tricky.

Here's what I have so far:

```
postComments = []

src = browser.page_source
#beautiful soup instance:
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, features="lxml")

bs4TagsComments = soup.find_all("li", attrs = {"class" : "social-details-social counts__item social-details-social-counts__comments"})
for tag in bs4TagsComments:
    strtag = str(tag)
    list_of_matches = re.findall('[,0-9]+',strtag)
    last_string = list_of_matches.pop()
    without_comma = last_string.replace(',','')
    commentsCount = int(without_comma)
    postComments.append(commentsCount)

print(postComments)
```

In theory, the above should work - however, all that is printed out is an empty list.
There are comment counts to pull and if there aren't, I should at least get a dict of '0's.

Answer (score 1):

With `Regex` was able to extract the value of comments. Try like below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import re

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/")
time.sleep(30) # to manually login

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html5lib')
regex = re.compile('.*social-details-social-counts__comments.*')
comments = soup.find_all('li',{'class': regex}) # find all 'li' tags that has `social-details-social-counts__comments` in it.
for comment in comments:
    value = comment.getText().replace('\n','').replace(' ', '') #  for text without whitespaces
    print(value)
```

```
1comment
1comment
14comments
5comments
29comments
4comments
3comments
...
```

For extracting comments count based on the post:

```
feeds = soup.find_all(code to find the feeds)

for feed in feeds:
    regex = re.compile('.*social-details-social-counts__comments.*')
    try:
        comments = feed.find('li',{'class': regex}).getText().replace('\n','').replace(' ', '')
    except:
        comments = None
```

Comment: Thanks! Got this working :)
How would I go about getting it to print '0comments' if there are no comments on a post?

Comment: @ZamenaJaffer - We need to figure out the `feeds` or `posts` first and then iterate over them to check if there are comments. Updated the answers for the same.